# Informix CDC API errors

Tags: informix, transactional-replication, oracle-cdc

I am getting errors while trying to run Informix CDC api.

1. I copied the code https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_11.50.0/com.ibm.cdc.doc/ids_cdc_060.htm  into cdcapi_INFORMIX.ec
2. Ran as informix user login, I am getting error CDC_ERRORCODE = CDC_E_APIVERS 
   I got few warnings while compiling the program but it compiled into a program CDCEXE. But doent seem to work. Could anyone provide me few pointers

> **check_version csdk**
>   Currently installed version: 3.50.FC5
>
> **ifx_getversion dmi**
>   IBM/Informix-Client SDK Version 3.50.FC5
>
> **ifx_getversion esql**
>   IBM/Informix-Client SDK Version 3.50.FC5
>   IBM/Informix EMBEDDED SQL for C Version 3.50.FC5
>   Copyright (C) 1991-2009 IBM
>
> > **esql -g -static -o CDCEXE cdcapi_INFORMIX.ec /opt/inf/sdk/lib/dmi/libdmi.a** "cdcapi_INFORMIX.ec", line 492:
> >     warning #2223-D: function "ldlong" declared
> >               implicitly
> >                             c_int8.data[0] = ldlong(databuf+INT8_LO_OFFSET);
> >                                              ^
>
> "cdcapi_INFORMIX.ec", line 558: warning #2223-D: function "ldbigint"
>   declared
>             implicitly
>                           ldbigintx(&c_bigint, databuf);
>                           ^
>
> "cdcapi_INFORMIX.ec", line 587: warning #2223-D: function "lddecimal"
>   declared
>             implicitly
>                           lddecimal(databuf, coldesc.colobj[col].colsize, &c_decimal);
>                           ^
>
> "cdcapi_INFORMIX.ec", line 687: warning #2223-D: function "rtypsize"
>   declared
>             implicitly
>           colsize = rtypsize(sqlda->sqlvar[col].sqltype,
>                     ^
>
> "cdcapi_INFORMIX.ec", line 747: warning #2223-D: function "ldlong"
>   declared
>             implicitly
>         lsn_hi = ldlong(databuf + TRUNCATE_LSN_HI_OFFSET);
>                  ^
>
> "cdcapi_INFORMIX.ec", line 778: warning #2223-D: function "ldlong"
>   declared
>             implicitly
>         tabid = ldlong(databuf+TABSCHEMA_USERDATA_OFFSET);
>                 ^
>
> "cdcapi_INFORMIX.ec", line 873: warning #2223-D: function "ldlong"
>   declared
>             implicitly
>         lsn_hi = ldlong(databuf + TXN_LSN_HI_OFFSET);
>                  ^
>
> "cdcapi_INFORMIX.ec", line 908: warning #2223-D: function "ldlong"
>   declared
>             implicitly
>         lsn_hi = ldlong(databuf + DISCARD_LSN_HI_OFFSET);
>                  ^
>
> "cdcapi_INFORMIX.ec", line 947: warning #2223-D: function "ldlong"
>   declared
>             implicitly
>         lsn_hi = ldlong(databuf + IUD_LSN_HI_OFFSET);
>                  ^
>
> "cdcapi_INFORMIX.ec", line 1019: warning #2223-D: function "ldlong"
>   declared
>             implicitly
>         cur_log_header.ch_size_hdr        = ldlong(a_recordbuf);
>                                             ^
>
> "cdcapi_INFORMIX.ec", line 1342: warning #2549-D: variable "recptr" is
>   used
>             before its value is set
>              memcpy(databuf, recptr, bytes_left_over_in_previous_buf);
>                              ^
>
> "cdcapi_INFORMIX.ec", line 1387: warning #2223-D: function "ldlong"
>   declared
>             implicitly
>                 hdrsize = ldlong(recptr);
>
> ---
>
> **Ran the program as**
>
> > ./CDCEXE -D db1 -T "bill.t1" -C "a,b" -T t2 -C "a,c" INFORMIXSERVER [server1] Connected to syscdcv1@server1 CDC_OPENSESS for server1
> >     server1 with  Timeout 300 Max recs per read 1
>
> CDC API 'cdc_opensess' Failed at cdcapi_INFORMIX.ec:1277.
>           CDCAPI_RETVAL = -83702,  CDC_ERRORCODE = CDC_E_APIVERS CDC Error Description is
>           The requested CDC API behavior version is not valid or is unsupported.
>
> Total buffers read: 0 Total records extracted: 0 Average recs per
>   buffer: 0.000000
>
> ---

Comment: Note that you should have `$INFORMIXDIR/demo/cdc/cdcapi.ec` on your machine which should contain the code that was delivered with your software, and which should, therefore, work with your software. The compilation warnings are not very satisfactory. Fixing them is harder than it looks. The function `lddecimal()` is declared in `$INFORMIXDIR/incl/public/decimal.h` but not in `$INFORMIXDIR/incl/esql/decimal.h` for reasons which elude me. Similarly, the function `ifxcdc_valisnull()` is `$INFORMIXDIR/incl/public/sqlhdr.h`, but not `$INFORMIXDIR/incl/esql/sqlhdr.h`. That doesn't even show for you.

Comment: thank you Jonathan

Answer (score 3):

The CDC error -83702 refers to a mismatch in the API version. Since your version of ESQL/C is 3.50.FC5 I presume your Informix server version is 11.50.FC5. This uses an earlier version (1.0) of the CDC API whilst the example code from the IBM Knowledge Center uses API version 1.1.

This problem can be resolved by upgrading the Informix server to 11.50.FC6 or later. The latest 11.50 version is 11.50.FC9W3.